# how to insert form data into MYSQL using python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

i am trying to insert the data entered into the web form into database table,i am passing the data to the function to insert the data,but it was not sucessful
below is my code

```
def addnew_to_database(tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date):
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin_operations', password='raghu',host='127.0.0.1',database='tracking_system')
    try:
        print tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("insert into track_table (tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date) values(tid,pid,usid,address,status,phno,email,ord_date,del_date)")
        cursor.execute("insert into user_table (tid,usid) values(tid,usid)")
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to commit your statements:

```
connection.commit()
```

and you need to add data to your insert statement:

```
cursor.execute('''insert into user_table (tid, usid) 
                  values ({}, {})'''.format(tid, usid))
```

(not tested)

---

**UPDATE**

i made a baby-example (and tested it):

database setup:

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> CREATE USER 'test_user' IDENTIFIED BY 'test_pass';
mysql> CREATE DATABASE test_db;
mysql> CREATE TABLE test_db.test_table (number INTEGER(16), string CHAR(16));
mysql> GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON test_db.* TO 'test_user'@'%';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

# test:
$ mysql -u test_user -D test_db -p
```

then this python code inserts data (very basic version; no exception handling, no transaction handling):

```
import mysql.connector as my

connection = my.connect(user='test_user', password='test_pass',
                        host='127.0.0.1', database='test_db')

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO test_table(number, string) VALUES({}, '{}')
               '''.format(43, 'hello world'))
connection.commit()    

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table")
print(cursor.fetchall())
connection.close()
```

note the quotes around `'{}'` where `.format` enters a string value.

this uses the following versions:

```
python3                 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
python3-mysql.connector 1.1.6-1
mysql                   5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

Comment: i had used connection.close()

Comment: if you did not set `autocommit` to `True`, this will not automatically commit. you will have to call `connection.commit()` before closing the connection. did you try it?

Comment: now i had tried it but row is set but data was not inserted in the table

Comment: oh, you do  not provide any data to your statemtents... i will update the answer. hang on...

Comment: then please update your question; post the bare minimum of code that you  have now and that reproduces your problem. does python print a traceback? or is there just no data in the database?

Comment: There is no data in the tables,and the values tid,pid,,,,, are variables that contains data to be inserted

Comment: i only posted how you insert (`tid, usid)` into the `user_table`; you have to update the other insert statement (the one for the `track_table` table) in a similar manner. is the `user_table` really empty now?

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError

ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'abcd' in 'field list' i had entered pid='abcd'

Comment: user_table is really empty

Comment: updated the code with a working example. hope that works for you too and you can build from there.